# PHP How do you define an array and reference it in a class?

Tags: php, arrays, class

I have written a `php class` to use in a small script to just run any query that I like from other scripts. *This is **NOT** going to be used publicly or in production*, and I'm aware of the huge security issue this poses!

I have done this as an excercise to see learn about classes etc... I seem to be having problems with one specific line in the code which is causing an error somewhere. I think it might be because I'm trying to return an array, and I think I haven't defined it properly in the class.

```
$this->resultOfQuery = mysqli_fetch_array($this->out_Resource, MYSQLI_ASSOC));
```

This is the whole code.

```
<?php

class GetRandomRecord {

//Connection
    public $CUDBName;   
    public $CUHost;     
    public $CUUser;     
    public $CUPassword; 
    public $in_SQL;
    public $out_Resource;
    public $CULink;  

    public $message;

    public $errors = array();         // is this correct?
    public $resultOfQuery = array();  // is this correct?

/****************************************************************/
    public function setSQL($value){
        $this->in_SQL = $value;
        return $this->in_SQL; 
    }

/****************************************************************/
    public function setConnectionString($db,$host,$user,$password){

        $this->CUDBName   = $db;
        $this->CUHost     = $host;
        $this->CUUser     = $user;
        $this->CUPassword = $password;

    }

/****************************************************************/
    public function runSQL() {

        $this->CULink  = mysqli_connect( $this->CUHost , $this->CUUser , $this->CUPassword , $this->CUDBName);

        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            $this->message = "Connection failed: ".mysqli_connect_error();
            return $this->message;
        }


        $this->out_Resource  =  mysqli_query($this->in_SQL , $this->CULink);


        if (!$this->out_Resource)
        {
            $this->errors['sql']      = $this->in_SQL; 
            $this->errors['eeDBName'] = $this->CUDBName;
            $this->errors['eeLink']   = $this->CULink;
            $this->errors['status']   = "false"; //There was a problem saving the data;

            mysqli_close($this->CULink);

            return json_encode($this->errors);
        }
        else
        {                   

        // success
            $this->resultOfQuery = mysqli_fetch_array($this->out_Resource, MYSQLI_ASSOC));
            mysql_close($this->CULink);     
            return $this->resultOfQuery;

        } // if (!mysql_query( $CUDBName , $sql , $CULink))



    }
/****************************************************************/

}//class

$recordGet = new getRandomRecord();

$recordGet->setConnectionString('databasename','localhost','username','password');

// select count from database
$tableName = "userList";

$countSQL = "select count(*) from $tableName";

$recordGet->setSQL($countSQL);

$result = $recordGet->runSQL();

print_r($result);

?>
```

Can you help me identify the problem?

**EDIT:** Actually I haven't got a specific error message. I have an `HTTP Error 500` which usually means my code is duff, and I narrowed it down by commenting sections of code until I found the line that caused it.

Comment: "...which is causing an error somewhere..." show error text

Comment: What is the error message showing..

Comment: Indeed, it's quite a chunk of code to comb over, so any other details, like the actual error message, would be more helpful.

Comment: check your error_logs

Comment: @Phantom Vineet1982 Romi Halasz I've updated the post.

Comment: and why is that $recordGet = new getRandomRecord(); instead of $recordGet = new GetRandomRecord();

Comment: **Check. Your. Error. Logs.** Figure out where they are and read them. They tell you what's wrong.

Comment: @WaqarAlamgir sorry typo. Should be camelCase.

Comment: is error_reporting enabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an extra close-paren on line 64.

```
$this->resultOfQuery = mysqli_fetch_array($this->out_Resource, MYSQLI_ASSOC));
```

The line should be:

```
$this->resultOfQuery = mysqli_fetch_array($this->out_Resource, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```